# How to update view angularjs from data server (api/nodejs/mongodb) by click

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to know how can I update a view from data server after an update with ng-click.

I use Daftmonk Mean stack generator.

I opened an other topic with code but no answer, maybe I'm on the wrong way [update/refresh angularjs ng-repeat with data from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258534/update-refresh-angularjs-ng-repeat-with-data-from-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out $watch and $apply

$watch will watch for a change and call $apply with a button

```
function MyController($scope) {

   $scope.myVar = 1;

   $scope.$watch('myVar', function() {
       alert('hey, myVar has changed!');
   });

   $scope.changeValueButton = function() {
      $scope.myVar = 2; // This will trigger $watch expression to kick in
   };

   $scope.updateButton = function() {
      $scope.apply();
   };

}
```